# Format() in Python Regex

Tags: python, regex

In the example below, I want {0} and {1} to be replaced by the arguments passed to format, and {2} should have the regex functionality with `\w{2}` of, "find two letter characters".  How do I do this?

```
q = re.search("{0}\w{2}b{1}\w{2}quarter".format('b', 'a'), search_me).group()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put literal `{`, `}` using `{{` and `}}`:

```
>>> "{0}\w{{2}}b{1}\w{{2}}quarter".format('b', 'a')
'b\\w{2}ba\\w{2}quarter'
```

Comment: +1, Beat me to it (stupid minimum character amount requirement in answer)